# Match columns after iterating through list of matrices in R

Tags: r

I've written a function that iterates through a list and outputs a data frame. The function has 3 arguments; an input list and a vector of integers, threshold. The input list will usually contain a couple matrices and other data frames. Each matrix has values that correspond to a specific value for a threshold and count. Count is the row index

The goal is find the threshold and count for the smallest value from each matrix and values from the other matrices that correspond to those thresholds and counts.

My function is as follows:

```
set.seed(123)

opti_count <- function(list, thres){
  
  best <- c()
  
  for(element in list){
    
    if(is.matrix(element)){
      
      best.index <- which(element == min(element),arr.ind = TRUE)
      
      best.thres <- thres[best.index[2]]
      
      temp <- cbind(best.index[1], best.thres,  element[best.index])
      
      for(mat in list){
        
        if(is.matrix(mat) && !(identical(mat,element))){
          
          temp <- cbind(temp, mat[best.index])
        }
      }
      
      best <- rbind(best, temp)
      
    }
    
  }
  return(best)
}

row_names <- seq(1:6)
column_names <- seq(0.1,0.6,by = 0.1)

RAD <- matrix(rnorm(36, 20, 3), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(row_names, column_names))
FAD <- matrix(rnorm(36, 1,2), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(row_names, column_names))
LAD <- matrix(rnorm(36, 0.5,0.2), nrow = 6, ncol = 6, dimnames = list(row_names, column_names))

my_list <- list(RAD, FAD, LAD)

print(opti_count(my_list, thres = column_names))
```

The output from the code:

> ```
>        best.thres                                
> [1,] 6        0.3 14.1001485  3.737205  0.7297615
> [2,] 6        0.6 -3.6183378 22.065921  0.1664116
> [3,] 6        0.6  0.1664116 22.065921 -3.6183378
> ```

My desired output is:

> ```
>  Count  Threshold        RAD       FAD        LAD
> 1   6       0.3    14.1001485  3.737205  0.7297615
> 2   6       0.6    22.065921 -3.6183378  0.1664116
> 3   6       0.6    22.065921 -3.6183378  0.1664116
> ```

Count and threshold values in the first row of the desired output selects the smallest RAD and the corresponding FAD & LAD. Count and threshold values in the second row selects the smallest FAD and corresponding RAD & LAD and so on.

I want to preserve the matrix names as column names in the output data frame as well. Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to start by putting your lists in a data frame, in tidy format:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- my_list |> 
  set_names(c("RAD", "FAD", "LAD")) |> 
  imap(\(data, name) as_tibble(data) |> 
         rownames_to_column("count") |> 
         mutate(grp = {{name}})) |> 
  list_rbind() |> 
  pivot_longer(-c(grp, count), names_to = "threshold")

df
# A tibble: 108 × 4
   count grp   threshold value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
 1 1     RAD   0.1        18.3
 2 1     RAD   0.2        21.4
 3 1     RAD   0.3        21.2
 4 1     RAD   0.4        22.1
 5 1     RAD   0.5        18.1
 6 1     RAD   0.6        21.3
 7 2     RAD   0.1        19.3
 8 2     RAD   0.2        16.2
 9 2     RAD   0.3        20.3
10 2     RAD   0.4        18.6
# … with 98 more rows
```

Then get the `count` and `threshold` value for each of the group minima:

```
targets <- df |> 
  arrange(count, threshold) |> 
  group_by(grp) |> 
  summarise(focus_row = count[value == min(value)],
            focus_col = threshold[value == min(value)]) 

targets
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  grp   focus_row focus_col
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>    
1 FAD   6         0.6      
2 LAD   6         0.6      
3 RAD   6         0.3
```

Finally, iterate over each entry in `targets` and grab the corresponding values from each group in `df`:

```
targets |> 
  group_by(grp) |> 
  group_map(\(data, key) df |> 
              group_by(grp) |> 
              summarise(target_val = value[count == data$focus_row &
                                             threshold == data$focus_col]) |> 
              mutate(count = data$focus_row,
                     threshold = data$focus_col,
                     target_grp = factor(key$grp, 
                                         ordered = TRUE, 
                                         levels = c("RAD", "FAD", "LAD")))) |> 
  list_rbind() |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, 
              values_from = target_val) |> 
  arrange(target_grp) |> 
  select(target_grp, count, threshold, RAD, FAD, LAD)

  target_grp count threshold   RAD   FAD   LAD
  <ord>      <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 RAD        6     0.3        14.1  3.74 0.730
2 FAD        6     0.6        22.1 -3.62 0.166
3 LAD        6     0.6        22.1 -3.62 0.166
```

Once the `group_map` finishes, you have all the data you need, the rest is just manipulating the data to get it in the format of your desired output.